# Create filter with $and condition, SQL to golang filter converter?

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have currently a working filter for .DeleteMany. It deletes all entries where **_id** is in the given array **vids**:

```
filter := bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$in", Value: vids}}}}
res, err := DB.Collection("data").DeleteMany(context.TODO(), filter)
```

Now I want to enhance the filter and add some **$and** condition to only delete entries where **_id** is in the given array **vids** and(!) the value of **providerid** is **1234**.

Sadly I'm stuck on how to do that in go. For me it is extremely hard to read and write such filters. Especially with all that bson.D, bson.M and []bson.D and the many curly brackets etc.

In SQL I would write **DELETE FROM data WHERE _id IN( {list} ) AND providerid=1234;**

Is there any SQL to golang mongodb filter converter?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
filter := bson.D{
    { "$and", []interface{}{
        bson.D{{ Key: "_id", Value: bson.D{{ Key: "$in", Value: vids }}}},
        bson.D{{ "providerid", 123}},
    }},
}
```

---

As per @VolkerSchmid comment

```
filter := bson.D{ { Key: "$and", Value: []interface{}{ bson.D{{ Key: "_id", Value: bson.D{{ Key: "$in", Value: vids }}}}, bson.D{{ Key: "providerid", Value: 123}}, }}, }
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but this triggers "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields" in VS Code. To get rid of this, I need to write like this:filter := bson.D{
  { Key: "$and", Value: []interface{}{
   bson.D{{ Key: "_id", Value: bson.D{{ Key: "$in", Value: vids }}}},
   bson.D{{ Key: "providerid", Value: 123}},
  }},
 }

But is there some code generator or such, making it more easy to write such filters?

Comment: Strange that mongodb needs us to write 10 opening curly brackets, 10 closing curly brackets and a set of square brackets just for such a simple filter... Some generator would be of great help.

Comment: yes, it works after adaption with Key: and Value:. Thanks for this! But the main part of my question was about a SQL to mongodb converter.

Comment: @VolkerSchmid https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/ https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/sql-query/ https://www.site24x7.com/tools/sql-to-mongodb.html

Comment: Gupta Thank you, this is a good start. But it just generates a mongodb search filter. It still lacks all the golang related things like interface, bson.D etc... It also adds some weird {"E": 1} to the query I dont understand. But only if the query is a DELETE query. But helpful anyway.

Comment: @VolkerSchmid https://github.com/codeStroke/MonGoConvertor

Comment: Gupta Thanks, but that does not do any filter string conversion?